# How to execute a jupyter notebook with parameters received from frontend?

Tags: reactjs, flask, jupyter-notebook

Beginner developer here! So my question is that I want to send an audio file from frontend to a Flask backend which would pass the audio to a jupyter notebook which would send back some textual result and display it on frontend. I would choose Flask as it is python based and I want to use React for frontend. Is it possible without involving other technologies? Thank you!

I couldn't find a straightforward answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter is in fact just a IDE, what you want to do is move all operation from it to some method that you will call from your flask backend.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I would rather keep things in notebook and call it with parameters. Is it possible for client to wait until it gets results?